# How to scale data in a log-lin regression

Tags: self-study, econometrics, scales, log-linear

I am currently doing exam revision, and I am stuck on a question in one of the past exams. It asks us to data scale the following equation:

$\ln W$ = 2.54 + 0.4`Educ` + 0.25`Exper` - 0.025`Exper`² + 0.29`Tenure` + *u*.

It asks us to scale *W* by 1/1000 (convert dollars into thousands of dollars) and `Educ` from years to quarters. In class we have been taught how to scale linear and log-log models but not log-lin.

The question asks us to calculate:

1. The new intercept
2. The new `Educ` coefficient
3. The new `Tenure` coefficient.

From my understanding I know that $\ln W$ change will be passed onto the slope. However, I am really unsure as to how any of the four above transform. I was hoping someone might be able to explain to me how to do it.
Thanks for you help and time.

Edit: So as the self-study tag suggested I am going to provide what I think is the best method I have tried:

So using the information that $\ln W$ was passed onto the intercept I first of all applied
$\ln (W/1000)$ which I then expanded to $\ln(W) - ln(1000)$

Then I got the equation

$\ln W$ = 2.54 + $\ln(1000)$ + 0.4`Educ` + 0.25`Exper` - 0.025`Exper`² + 0.29`Tenure` + *u*.

I was confused after this point because in the textbook it suggested for log-log that the slope are invariant to the changes in scale, however this is log-lin so I assumed that the scale would still apply for `Educ` & `Tenure`.

Therefore for `Educ` I used the scaling of 0.4 * `w1`/`w2` : where `w1` = $1/1000$ and `w2` = $1/4$

From this I got 0.0016.

Similarly by using the scale `w1` = $1/1000$ and `w4` = $1$ I got $0.00029$ for `Tenure` new coefficient.

However other people in my class have informed me this was wrong (although they have a better alternative themselves), most of them arguing that the coefficients of the independent variables should not change because it has a log.

Please forgive me for the formatting too. I am relatively new to this.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info), making any further edits to your question as needed.

Comment: Note that $\log(kx) = \log(k)+\log(x)$. That combined with what you've already learned about the linear-linear case should be sufficient to work it out.

Comment: Forget about the extra variables and work through this problem with just one independent variable, such as `Educ`. Now you can draw scatterplots showing what is going on. You should find that the change in units of $W$ merely translates the entire scatterplot up or down by some constant amount. What does that do to the slope of any line that is fit to the points?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I understand that the dependent variable transformation is reflected in the slope. However I am really just having trouble trying to get the new slopes for `B1` & `B4` because in our lecture notes it tells us to use `w1/w2` or if they are all logs then the slopes don't change, however if $ln W$ transformation is invariant to the slope then should it be that `Educ` is only transformed by $1/(1/4)$ - that doesn't really seem right. Thanks.